# How to use Apply for Function Application

Tags: scala, scalaz

I have the following validation logic:

```
  def one(a : String) : Validation[String, Int] =
    if (a == "one") {
      Success(1)
    } else {
      Failure("Not One")
    }

  def two(a : String) : Validation[String, Int] =
    if (a == "two") {
      Success(2)
    } else {
      Failure("Not Two")
    }

  def validate (a : String) = (one(a) |@| two(a)){_  + _}
```

According to the Scalaz documentation:

```
  /**
   * DSL for constructing Applicative expressions.
   *
   * `(f1 |@| f2 |@| ... |@| fn)((v1, v2, ... vn) => ...)` is an alternative to `Apply[F].applyN(f1, f2, ..., fn)((v1, v2, ... vn) => ...)`
   *
   * `(f1 |@| f2 |@| ... |@| fn).tupled` is an alternative to `Apply[F].applyN(f1, f2, ..., fn)(TupleN.apply _)`
   *
   * Warning: each call to `|@|` leads to an allocation of wrapper object. For performance sensitive code, consider using
   *          [[scalaz.Apply]]`#applyN` directly.
   */
```

How do I convert the validate function to use `apply2`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type constructor for `Validate` takes two parameters, but `Apply` can only be parameterized by a type constructor of arity one. You need a special trick called type lambda which allows us to curry the type definition:

```
def validate(a : String) = Apply[({type λ[Int] = Validation[String, Int]})#λ].apply2(one(a), two(a)){_  + _}
```

Comment: Yes I noticed that Apply was taking a type constructor of arity one but stumbled because Validation takes two.

Comment: Yeah.. This is a common trick, really ugly but that's how it's done for now. Basically you create an ad-hoc type (lambda type) that takes one parameter, which is what `Apply` wants, which creates a new type with two generic types, and then you "apply that type" with # (it's like ok now take what we just created). Note that I hardcoded the two types into String and Int. Check out e.g. [this](http://like-a-boss.net/2014/09/27/type-lambda-in-scala.html) or [this](https://blog.adilakhter.com/2015/02/18/applying-scalas-type-lambda/).